# Datatable (without pagination) > missing parameters in form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

**#3 EDIT => CAUSE FOUND!**

So I found that *what is causing the issue is **Datatable***. Even if I'm not using pagination, Datatable is limiting the number of rows the form can POST.

```
jQuery('#tblStats').DataTable( {
   dom: 'ft',
   ordering: false,
   jQueryUI: true,
   scrollY: "400px",
   deferRender: true,
   scroller: true,
   scrollCollapse: true,
   language: {
       search: "<%= t('app.bouton.filter') %>",
       infoEmpty: "<%= t('app.datetables.sZeroRecords') %>"
   }
});
```

Any ideas on how to avoid that limit and continue using Datatable?

I've already tried this but still the same:
https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-how-to-submit-all-pages-form-data/

Thanks!

**INITIAL MESSAGE**

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out why I have some missing parameters when submitting a form.

Inside the form there is a table that is dynamically populated. 10 parameters are sent for each row. **The submit works fine with small data** but it seems to have a limit at 1898 parameters. Some times the parameters of the first 5 or 6 rows are missing and some times are the parameters of the last rows. This is totally random. But the limit seems to be always the same: no more than 1898 parameters are sent.

**I get no error at all. The parameters are just not sent.** This is happening in production server as well than in development server. The servers are different and the OS is different as well.

Rails version is 2.3.18. Ruby version is 1.8.7.

Does anyone have any idea of what's going on?

Thanks in advance for your help!

**#1 EDIT**

Following the advice of [Oshanz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3011280/oshanz) I have found passenger's config file. In my case:

```
$>/home/alberto/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@dev/gems/passenger-4.0.37/resources/templates/standalone/config.erb
```

In the file there is a parameter "client_max_body_size" inside the http{}. It has a default value of 1048m. Even if this seems big enough I have changed it to 2048m.
**Unfortunately this didn't work and the result is still the same.**

**#2 EDIT**

So I'm still having the problem.

As I commented below I'm using a `form_remote_tag` with a dynamically populated table inside. This will submit using XMLHttpRequest in the background instead of the regular reloading POST arrangement. 
This generates:

```
<form action="/wizi_comm/stats" method="post" onsubmit="Element.hide('err');Element.show('spinner');; new Ajax.Request('/wizi_comm/stats', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, onComplete:function(request){Element.hide('spinner');Element.show('mainBd');}, parameters:Form.serialize(this)}); return false;">
```

I have also tested using `form_tag` and the result is the same. Some parameters are just not sent.

```
<form action="stats" method="post">
```

I have check passenger's config files with no luck. *I do really need some ideas here:*
**Do you think this is due to a configuration somewhere?**
**Do you think I should change the way I'm submitting the form?**

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you sure you're sending it via POST request and not GET? GET is quite limited in size.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure ...

`Processing WiziCommController#stats (for 192.168.xxx.xx at 2019-01-16 09:28:06) [POST]
  Session ID: 9064d894effdee67af170b3f822ac0e0
  Parameters: {...}`

Comment: what is your web server? if nginx try increasing "client_max_body_size"

Comment: I am using phusion passenger. On production I load the module using Apache but not in development. I am trying to find out if this a passenger related thing? Maybe a parameter to change as with nginx?

Comment: Some code would be helpful here. How is the data `sent for each row`? Is it a json you utilize with js? I can only guess here... The same as `GET` is limited also `POST` has this issue since since it passes the params via url.

Comment: The data is sent using a form_remote_tag:

`<% form_remote_tag(:url => {:action => :stats} do -%>
<table>...</table>
<% end %>`

Comment: I have also tested with a `form_tag` with same results if that helps ... :)

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

I did some tests with Datatable's based solutions as [rows().data()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().data()). I was still missing some rows. I was also getting some errors from the API.

At this point I think that other JS libraries on the project are interfering with jQuery. I will study this when I will have the time.

What I finally did is to remove Datatable's initialisation on the table and to use a pure CSS solution to do the scroll. If someone is interested, my solution is based on this:

[Pure CSS solution scroll table](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/CrSpu/557/)

```
table.scroll {
    width: 716px; /* 140px * 5 column + 16px scrollbar width */
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

table.scroll tbody,
table.scroll thead tr { display: block; }

table.scroll tbody {
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

table.scroll tbody td,
table.scroll thead th {
    width: 140px;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

table.scroll thead th:last-child {
    width: 156px; /* 140px + 16px scrollbar width */
}

table.scroll thead tr th { 
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    /*text-align: left;*/
}

table.scroll tbody { border-top: 2px solid black; }

table.scroll tbody td:last-child, thead th:last-child {
    border-right: none !important;
}
```

Thanks again for your help !